# Изображения из mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Такая проблема:

```
$q = "select * from foto";
$r = mysql_query($q);
$result = mysql_query($q) or die('Error, query failed');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { echo "$row[content]"; }
```

Выводит полную ерунду типа

> "����&��>e����S�����{Q�`��"

Как исправить?

Comment: База отдает в cp1251 (или подобном), а пытаетесь отобразить как utf8. Настраивайте кодировки.

Comment: а поле `content` какого типа?

Comment: Я бы еще спросил, с хедером он отправляет изображение. скорее всего у автора text/plain

Comment: ну так и я про то) а то все ринулись кодировку ломать)))

Comment: Зачем вы выводите данные через этот костыль?

    "$row[content]"

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от выбранной Вам кодировкой.

Вначале вставьте вот такую строку и все будет работать!

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES cp1251');
или
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
```

Это используется для указания кодировки записываемых данных, а в Вашем случае необходимо поменять либо кодировку БД или кодировку Вашего проекта!

**UPD**

Для начало проще всего поменять кодировку на сайте, делается это изменением в файле .htaccess:
Добаляете/изменяете код:

```
php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
```

И потом в файле php.ini правите строку:

```
mbstring.func_overload 2
```

**Обновление**

Поясню более подробно! Надо написать точно такую строку (ничего изменять не надо):

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
```

Вставляешь эту строку второй, после:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
```

Если у Вас foto2  является бинарным типом. То для вывода на сайте нужно указать `header: header("Content-type: image/jpg ");`

Указывается вначале шаблона(view).

Comment: Я может не понял, совсем не понимаю в mysql



    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    if (!$conn) { die('Ошибка соединения:' . mysql_error());}
    mysql_select_db("t_db_06_11") or die(mysql_error());
    $q = "select * from foto2";
    $r =  mysql_query('SET $q utf8');
  
    $result = mysql_query($q) or die('Error, query failed');
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { echo "$row[img]"; }


ничего не изменилось

Comment: Ты точно не понимаешь) img какой тип? Если ты там хранишь саму картинку, то ты хоть какую кодировку укажи - не получишь картинку.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
```

вот это после подключения к базе, и рекомендую весь сайт перевести в эту кодировку

Answer (score 0):

Можете еще принудительно устанавливать кодировку БД через `mysql_set_charset();`